# Help me to choose Flex framework

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, frameworks

In my university a have to make a project: XMPP client on Adobe Flex. On this occasion I've decided to learn any architectural framework and to use it in my project. Could you advise me, what framework would be the best one for the XMPP client? What are advantages and disadvantages of this or that framework?
Thank you.

Comment: Don't have experience so I won't post this as an answer but the google answer is XIFF from what I've seen here's an example: http://leejava.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/xmpp-client-in-flex-with-actionscript-3/ do you have a list of possibilities you're thinking of using?

Comment: @shaunhusain, I'v heard a bit about XIFF, and if i'm not mistaken, it's a library for XMPP usage. But i'm wondering about framework, to build my application architecture on.

Comment: okay didn't understand the question exactly.  The Flex framework itself provides everything you need to make a basic application and there's no need to introduce dependency injection or other features provided by frameworks like SWIZ or Robotlegs.  What's the scope of the project (how long do you have, whats the likelihood of it being a continued project that requires heavy programming to an interface and multiple implementations?). Cairngorm allows for a clean MVC with the small changes, but no dependency injection (basically it's a controller/event/command setup).

Comment: sorry couldn't fit it all in one.  If you're just getting started with Flex I'd suggest avoiding the other frameworks until you have a solid understanding of what can be done with the flex framework itself.  Also I've seen issues arise in applications using modules and swiz where things got messy with the model injection.  If you do decide to use one of those frameworks and will be using modules I suggest you test early.

Comment: @shaunhusain, thanks for your explanation, and what would personally you choose? I think, i'm quite ok at Flex itself, but i've decided to go farther. It's just an educational project, i think it's exactly the case to get acquainted with some framework :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timofei,

Sorry to do this to ya but I can't give you a straight answer, like Flextras said, it's too dependent upon the scenario.

For example, when I'm doing a mom and pop site for say family or friends generally speaking I don't need any framework to accomplish the goals of the site and to do so in a clean enough way for me to continue working on it in the future (and not worry myself with framework bugs deprecation in newer releases and so on, assuming I save the source).

If I'm working with a group of developers choosing an architecture that allows us to work independently and not tightly couple our classes, then some sort of framework becomes a discussion (lately this discussion has gone to SWIZ or Robotlegs, and as Flextras mentioned it seems more developers are favoring Robotlegs though I haven't heard or seen any substantial argument for one over the other).

I think its great that you're exploring this kind of thing while in school still I wasn't really exposed to it all until I started working, but at the same time you don't want to be using a bazooka to kill a fly.  When I first was first hired (a couple of years ago) Cairngorm was being used heavily (and for a large part still is), although this worked fairly well and we had an extension on top of it already some of the developers here (I was just a talker/pusher) from scratch built an MVC architecture.  It does everything Cairngorm does plus quite a bit more and now we have people in house who have an absolutely clear understanding of the inner workings of the MVC framework, obviously if a framework is old "enough" it will undergo "enough" use cases/testing that you don't need to know the inner workings but I certainly don't think it hurts.

Since, you aren't under a tight deadline I'd suggest just giving each of these a shot in a small project and see how they pan out and you'll probably realize that you can't see any substantial difference until you start getting into a more complex program (your program will likely look more complicated with RobotLegs or SWIZ in the basic form but once this is made into something more advanced you'd likely end up with less of your own code using one of these).  Also this will help you more than anyone else's loyalty to a particular framework.

Shaun

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

A few reasons to use a framework:

1. Usually results in a more structured application that other developers can understand and that YOU can understand when you come back and look at it months or years later.
2. You benefit from the time and effort spent by other developers who have hunted down and fixed framework bugs.  If you roll your own, you lose out on these time savings.
3. It's often easier to ask for help when trying to figure out the best way to tackle a particular issue because your application is structured in a way that anyone else familiar with that framework can quickly parse.
4. You make yourself more marketable as a developer as you gain skill with widely used frameworks.

Reasons not to use a framework:

1. The scope of your project is very small.  A framework can be considered overkill in certain situations.  Just keep in mind that often what starts out as small has a way of growing into something larger or morphing into something else entirely.

For what it's worth I'm currently using Robotlegs for most projects and it's really made my life easier.  Once you get over the initial learning curve it's very simple & quick to work with.

Answer (score 2):

"Best" is subjective.

A framework is intended to solve a problem.  I suggest you first define what problems you need to solve in this project and then look at frameworks to see if any of them would help.

I cold tell you that Cairngorm is the most used, but least talked about.  I could tell you that that Robotlegs is the most popular right now in the community.  I could tell you that Swiz just released a new version. I could tell you that PureMVC has support across multiple languages.

None of these would prove that a certain framework is right for you.  In the end, it framework choice doesn't matter.

Comment: That's why i'm asking people here. I do not have my subjective opinion, as i'm not familiar with any of them. Another criterion for me is popularity and demand today. So, could you tell me, what would personally you choose in my case?

Comment: @Timofei Davydik You didn't define the problems you are trying to solve, so I can't tell you which framework will best to help solve them.  You need to do some work for yourself, there is no single magic answer we can give you.

Comment: I'm just looking for an experienced developer's subjective opinion :)

Comment: @Timofei Davydik You haven't given us enough information for us to give you an answer.  I still say "The framework choice doesn't matter."

Answer (score 1):

Well I am using [robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org) and I am very happy with it. It uses Dependency Injection and utilizes the MVCS design pattern which on your case should be useful cause of the requests you have to make to the server. It is simple and it isn't bloated with features. I can't find any big disadvantage except its simplicity ( if this can be considered as a disadvantage).

Answer (score 1):

I'll add one more recommendation to this list: the parsley framework is excellent. We have been using it for more than 18 months in a very large, complex Flex app that front ends our commercial product. I've also used it in some smaller adjunct tools and some private projects and continue to be very happy with it.

It's an IOC style framework that really tries to get out of your way as much as possible. Note, however, that it specifically does *not* attempt to impose an architectural style on your code. You can follow MVC, MVP or nothing as you see fit. As such, its learning curve is less than other frameworks mentioned here, but the amount of "guidance" it provides to you in structuring your own code is also less.

Check out http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/

Answer (score 1):

As people have said already, you probably don't need a framework if this is a smallish type project, you'll end up over engineering it.

If this is a larger project I've used both Cairngorm and Swiz (and investigated the others out there.  We have moved away from Cairngorm as it simply creates far too much boiler plate code that you have to write.  It also follows older patterns and requires a massive dependency on the modellocator and large controller classes.

Swiz is lightweight and based on more modern dependency injection.  It is more testable, lightweight, portable, and flexible.  It has a few quirks here and there, but usually you can figure these out on the google group or their online docs.

Answer (score 0):

as a side note, XMPP on Actionscript is not very mature. As early advice, don't try to test with Google Talk servers. They don't do XMPP the same way that XIFF is designed to support (at least since 2 months ago). If you want your own jabber/xmpp server, here is a suggestion: download oracle's virtual box and run your own ejabberd server locally for testing. (http://www.turnkeylinux.org/ejabberd)